# How to replace a hex value in a file with other hex values using python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I have hex values in a file named `hex_values.txt` in this format:

```
0x52 0x49 0x46 0x46 0x62 0x9B 0x04 0x00 0x57 0x41 0x56 0x45 0x66 
0x6D 0x74 0x20 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x40 0x1F 
0x00 0x00 0x80 0x3E 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x64 0x61 0x74 
0x61 0x3E 0x9B 0x04 0x00 0xE8 0x01 0xF9 0x01**
```

I want to change the first few values to `0X00`.

I have to replace some values with `0xAA`. Copy the contents of `file1` to `file2` and replace the values.

How can it be done?

Note: `file1` contains the hexadecimal values.

I tried using:

```
file1 = open("hex_values.txt", "r"); #opening hex_values.txt file
read1 = file1.read();

#copying content of hex_values.txt to file2
file2 = open("file2.txt", "w");
file2.write(read1);

for i in range(0,10):          #ranging for first 10 values     
    file2.seek(i)
    file2.write('0x00')        #replacing hex value with 0x00
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Problem what am facing is, the contents of file1 is being copied to file2 but am not able to replace the values.

The solution what am expecting is shown below:

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x56 0x45 0x66 0x6D 0x74 0x20 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x40 0x1F 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x3E 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x64 0x61 0x74 0x61 0x3E 0x9B 0x04 0x00 0xE8 0x01 0xF9 0x01

Comment: If your code doesn't work, please describe what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi khelwood, the contents of file1 is being copied to file2 and i am not able to replace the values to '0x00' in file2 (which is supposed to be happened)

Comment: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x56 0x45 0x66 
0x6D 0x74 0x20 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x40 0x1F 
0x00 0x00 0x80 0x3E 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x64 0x61 0x74 
0x61 0x3E 0x9B 0x04 0x00 0xE8 0x01 0xF9 0x01                                    [ I need file2 to be like this ]

Comment: Please [edit] the extra information into your question; don't put it in comments. See [ask].

Comment: Also, provide exactly what the output file (file2.txt) looks like, because I think the beginning of the file is going to be telling.

Comment: I have mentioned it as the solution what am expecting at the end of the question, glibdud.